# Pub failed to delete entry because it was in use by another process. This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file in the directory open in

Tags: flutter, dart

I just updated flutter, now it started showing this. Any help??[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onvpl.jpg)

Comment: Sometimes, just turn off the system and re-start again works for such errors.

Comment: yeah I tried that but didn't work well

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the answer. Just reinstall the flutter again, it will work. And make sure the directory is same as previous or else you have to change the path and everything all. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Here's what i have done:

1. I have tried "flutter clean" not worked
2. then have run "flutter pub cache repair" not worked
3. also deleted temp files by windows key + R and %temp% not worked
4. finally opened the "cmd as administrator" and then run "flutter packages get" in project folder. It Worked!! :)
```